# AUTO_INCREMENT en MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Hola amigos tenia duda en algo sobre el AUTO_INCREMENT en mysql

[DOCUMENTACIÓN OFICIAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html)

Estaba leyendo la documentacion pero no lo mencionan asi que asumo que no es posible establecer que mi auto_increment se vaya aumentando NO de 1 en 1 sino que sea por ejemplo de 15 en 15.

intente hacerlo como en SQLServer estableciendo en mi:

```
CREATE TABLE table(
id int not null primary key auto_increment=40
);
```

Sin embargo me muestra error en el simple hecho de declararlo asi.

Mi pregunta es:
Hay una manera de hacer que mis INSERTS en cada tabla sean con id AUTO_INCREMENT distinto de uno en uno? Existe alguna alternativa para establecerlo?

Saludos Amigos!

Comment: El Step del autoincrement puede ser modificado en la configuración del MySQL o durante la sesión http://buysql.com/mysql/54-how-to-set-autoincrement-step.html Sin embargo en ambos casos afectaría todas las tablas, por lo que pienso que la mejor forma de hacerlo para que pueda tener un incremento diferente por tabla sería diseñar una función o un disparador.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿Realmente quieres que todas las tablas aumenten su valor auto  incremental a un determinado ritmo del establecido por defecto? Si ese fuera el requerimiento (lo cual sería extraño), ten en cuenta que si cambias la configuración al nivel del manejador para todas las tablas, todas las inserciones que ocurran después de haber hecho ese cambio asumirán ese ritmo de incremento, en la sesión activa si haces un cambio a nivel de sesión o conexión actual,  o peor aún, en todas las futuras inserciones si cambias la configuración global.

Si quieres que todas las tablas **presentes y futuras**<sup>1</sup> de esa base de datos tengan esa característica es evidente que lo mejor sería hacer un cambio a nivel de configuración.

Ahora bien, si solamente quieres que eso ocurra en una tabla en específico o en algunas tablas (lo cual sería lo más normal), sería mejor programar un `TRIGGER` que lo haga.

Algo así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER increment_by_two BEFORE INSERT ON tabla
  FOR EACH ROW 
    SET NEW.id = (SELECT MAX(id) + 2 FROM tabla);
```

Así, cada vez que ocurra una inserción **en esa tabla**, el `TRIGGER` establecerá el valor del `id` al valor de `MAX(id) + 1`.

Si actualmente `id` es igual a `1`, en las próximas inserciones:

```
id
------
3
5
7
9
... MAX(id) + 2
```

---

#### Notas

1. **Presentes y futuras** bien en negrita. Si dejas una configuración cambiada en alguna parte ...o ¡en cientos o miles de partes! (porque en 2019 era un requerimiento global) y el sistema evoluciona en un futuro (en 2023 se agregaron ala base de datos tablas que deben comportarse normalmente, incrementando de 1 en 1), podrías encontrarte con datos inconsistentes, debido a que cuando se conecta ese módulo que cambia la configuración, y en ese módulo ocurren inserciones en cualquiera de las tablas creadas a partir de 2023, las mismas se crean con los `id` alterados. ¿Y si hay varios millones de registros cuando te vienes a dar cuenta del error?  Personalmente considero que no es bueno cambiar el ritmo de auto incremento a nivel de configuración de la base de datos.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @A. Cedano

Answer (score 1):

Por favor, ejecute la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT @@ auto_increment_increment
```

El valor debe ser 1, configúrelo en el valor que requieras.

```
SET @@ auto_increment_increment = 1;
```

> Nota: Este cambio es visible solo para la conexión actual.

Para configurarlo globalmente para que otras conexiones también puedan ver el cambio, debe configurarlo.

```
SET @@ GLOBAL.auto_increment_increment = "el valor que requieras";

SET @@ SESSION.auto_increment_increment = "el valor que requieras";
```

Ahora otras conexiones pueden ver este cambio.

Más:

Este valor se restablecerá si reinicia su servidor MySQL. Para que este cambio sea permanente, debe escribir esta variable en la sección [mysqld] de su archivo my.cnf [para linux] o my.ini [para ventanas].

```
[mysqld]
auto-increment-increment = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar con:

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=2;
SET @@auto_increment_offset=2;
```

Comment: Gracias por comentar @mariovzc, no entiendo su respuesta, podria porfavor explicarme en donde utilizo eso?
Parece una parte de un Stored Procedure. Saludos